# Git desktop to desktop clone access

Tags: git

I am working to setup Git in our environment.  I have ssh setup and working for windows to linux server; we can clone, pull and push just fine.
Where i am having issues is from windows desktop to windows desktop.  I can ssh in to a team member desktop with my user account.  I can even create a git repository there in a shared location.  However, if i try to then clone that repository to my desktop i get an error message:

```
 fatal: ''/d/git/test2'' does not appear to be a git repository
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

However, that location is a git repo as confirmed through my ssh session into that machine:

> PS D:\git\test2> ls

```
Directory: D:\git\test2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM                hooks
d-----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM                info
d-----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM                objects
d-----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM                refs
-a----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM            104 config
-a----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM             73 description
-a----        5/23/2018   7:58 AM             23 HEAD
```

What i am trying to achieve is the ability for our team members to push and pull between themselves using ssh without having to add the extra hop to the linux server when not necessary.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow! However, it seems like your question has more to do with setting up your networks correctly to nicely interoperate. Maybe SuperUser or Networks is a better site to ask this question?

Comment: What exactly is the command (and arguments) you're using when you try, on your desktop, to clone the repo you created on the other windows machine?

Comment: `git clone ssh://<myuser>@<remotedesktop_name>:/d/git/test2`  it then prompts for the password which it accepts as incorrect password entry fails with a different message

Comment: Don't you need an ssh server running? Or does windows support it out of the box?